# Making a async function inside useEffect, and use await inside the while loop in the function, seems doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, async-await, promise, react-hooks, ethers.js

Did anyone meet some questions like me? I make an async function inside useEffect,  and call it. In the async function, I have a while loop, and use await inside the while loop, but it seems like doesn't work, console.log(productsList.length) will print 0, and when I try to use productsList.map to return some components, also return nothing

```
useEffect(() => {
        async function callProduct(){
            let a=5
            while (a>0) {
                const item = await contract.getProduct(a)
                await setProductsList([...productsList,item]])
               a--
            }
        }
        callProduct()
        console.log(productsList.length)
    },[])
```

Answer (score 2):

Because the new state only updates when the component re-render so you should put `console.log` inside useEffect with dependencies to check.

```
useEffect(() => {
    async function callProduct() {
        let a = 5;
        const newProductList = [];
        while (a > 0) {
            const item = await contract.getProduct(a);
            newProductList.push(item);
            a--;
        }

        setProductsList(newProductList);
    }
    callProduct();
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
    console.log(productsList.length)
}, [productsList])
```

Answer (score 2):

*All* functions in JS return right away after processing each step, whether they are async or not. `async` functions just return a promise, but they still return without waiting for anything. So your `console.log` will execute right away showing the length of the product list. BTW, even *if* the `setProductList` had executed, the `productList` state variable would still be a the same as before because useState setters don't apply right away.

Just put your console.log outside of your useEffect. Once `getProduct` returns, it will set the variable and your component will refresh, printing the console.log at that point.

Comment: But when I try to use productsList.map, it also nothing return the code is {productsList.length && (productsList.map(item=>(<div>........</div>)))}

Comment: have you added a console.log after your getProduct to see whether that ever returns an item?

Comment: I think my parameter has some problem